# Proof that angles are equal given that the length of a segment is minimized

Tags: geometry

> I am attempting to prove that $\angle APX$ is equal to $\angle BPY$ when $XP + PY$ is minimized.
>
> [image]

Thi problem is part of some extra practice in math class. We were mostly focused on ellipses during class, so I have a suspicion that this relates to the reflection property of ellipses, though I am not entirely sure yet. I could maybe see X and Y as focal points and the line AB to be a tangent line that intersects the ellipse at P.

Comment: Even when you don't know where to start with a problem, you can provide context that helps others assist you. For instance, if this is a textbook exercise, then what topic(s) were covered in the chapter? If it's a contest or online challenge, then what's the target audience? The more you can say, the better, so that people don't waste time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level.

Comment: First fix the question so it makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so you mean that you have to choose point $P$ accordingly.  Is this right?

Comment: This is not how you should choose a title for a question :) Please be more careful. The title of this question does not provide any useful information.

Comment: What should the title be then? I can't think of a good title here

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh Personally, I agree with the OP, about the title.  Geometry questions like this one don't lend themselves to an explanatory (meaningful) title.

Comment: @user2661923 With all due respect, I disagree :) Maybe this was a better title: "Proof that angles are equal given that the length of a segment is minimized". I'm not sure if this is the best title. However, at least it is more specific than just mentioning "Geometry" in the title!

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this in mind for future questions

Comment: You claim that some property is minimized. This implies that there should be at least one variable with respect to which the property is minimized. Could you identify the variable(s) as well as the parameters which remain constant?

Comment: @user I also was confused about this, because the OP's description of the problem wasn't clear.  $X$ and $Y$ are **fixed** points in $\Bbb{R^2}$, as is the line segment $(\overline{AB})$.  The only *variable*, is that the point $P$ is *some unknown* point on the line segment $(\overline{AB})$ that is to be chosen so that the sum of the lengths of the two line segments $(\overline{XP})$ and $(\overline{YP})$ is minimized.

Comment: @user2661923 This is of course clear from the accepted answer, but not from the question itself.  And OP obviously does not care about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof is to reflect for example $Y $ over the segment $(AB)$ to get point $Y'$ then the distance $XP+PY'$ is minimal if  $X$, $P$, $Y'$ are on a same line which is your condition.

Comment: Nice telepathy, assuming that the OP intends that a point $P$ must be chosen on $\overline{AB}$ so that the sum of the distances from $X$ to $P$ and from $Y$ to $P$ are minimized.